# How to loop over every line in a buffer?

Tags: iteration

I am searching for some kind of `reduce` function, which loops through every line of a buffer, but I can not find it. Does anybody know the name of such a function?

Something similar to Perl

```
while (<>) {
  ...
}
```

Or a `dolist` for buffer lines.

Comment: Found just this: https://github.com/Wilfred/loop.el#loop-for-each-line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slightly more idiomatic example:

```
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (not (eobp))
  ...
  (forward-line 1))
```

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19538/15748.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a while loop using the function `forward-line` as your test. If `forward-line` reaches the end of the buffer, it returns the number of lines it wanted to move but couldn't. That leads to the following loop:

```el
(save-excursion  ;; save our starting position
  (goto-char (point-min))    ;; go to the beginning of the buffer
  (while (< (forward-line) 1)    ;; move forward one line
                                 ;; until forward line returns a non-zero value
    (end-of-line)    ;; go to the end of the line
    (insert ";; I made it to here!")))    ;; insert a comment
```

The while loop continues as long as `forward-line` returns 0, which it does when it is able to move. It will return 1 when it can't move any further.

Comment: Does this skip the first line?